# A property of a 3-regular graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a 3-regular graph with $n$ vertices. Show that there exists a partition $V(G)=V_1\uplus V_2$ so that the number of edges in $G$ with one endpoint in $V_1$ and one endpoint in $V_2$ is at least $n$.

I have no idea how to approach this problem. Usually I use induction but here it doesn't seem to suit since $G$ is 3-regular.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we want to color the vertices of the graph red and blue such that at least $n$ edges are "interesting", meaning that they connect vertices of different colors.

Start with a random coloring.

As long as there are fewer than $n$ interesting edges, there must be at least one vertex that touches less than $2$ interesting edges. Flipping the color of that vertex will *increase* the number of interesting edges by either $1$ or $3$.

Comment: very nice! thanks!